# sharepoint 2013 server public facing site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement to create a public facing site in sharepoint 2013 server and admin can login and add,update and delete

How to implement this?

Any suggestions would be appreicated

Comment: Office 365/SharePoint Online has a super easy way to implement this scenario -- just create a 'public website' from within sharepoint administration. I'm assuming your actually using an on-premise setup though, although the kind of minimum setup you would need for an O365 plan is very inexpensive (starts at $7/month in the US!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Authoring and Staging server topology.

You can set two farms -

Authoring: For editing the content. This farm will be exposed only to authenticated users.

Staging: For showing the content. This farm will have anonymous access enabled.

You can transfer the content using content deployment mechanisms in Central Admin.

This is a wide topic to discuss. So if you are facing any particular difficulty then please let me know.

Thanks

For reference:

[Why Use Authoring and Production Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/why-use-an-authoring-server-and-a-production-server)

[Build Site in SP13](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163242(v=office.15).aspx)

[Cross Site Publishing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635877(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: thanks alot for ur answer, but i have no idea regarding this so need to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a single farm. What you need to do is create and configure your Web Application to support both Anonymous and Claims-based authentication. Public users will continue to access your site as anonymous and when Admin wants to change the content, he can sign-in and change the content.